# If $A \subset E \subset B$ and $m(A) = m(B)$ are measurable, then $E$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm aware this has been asked before, so don't link any questions, nor mark as duplicate. I'm here to inquire about my method of proof.

I'm working out of Stein and Shakarchi, Real Analysis; problem 26 of Chapter 1.

---

The statement is as follows:

Suppose that $A \subset E \subset B$ and $m(A) = m(B) < \infty $ where $A, B, E \in \mathbb{R}^d \ $. Show that $E$ is measurable. Measure here means Lebesgue measurable.

---

I would like to specifically prove this with limits:

By the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ suppose that $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence that converges to $A$, each measurable so that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(A_n) =m(A)$ and similarly $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}m(B_n) =m(B)$. Then if $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence that converges to $E$, by the squeeze theorem of Calculus, we have that A=B=E. Now since A and B are measurable, E is measurable.

Comment: I don't understand. You know that IF $E$ is measurable, then $m(A)=m(E)=m(B)$ because $A\subset B$ implies $m(A)\leq m(B)$. So you need to show that $E$ is measurable.

Comment: @T. Bongers already pointed out the big flaw of your argument. Another issue is that you have not well defined what does it mean for a set $A_n$ to converge to a set $A$. Your argument only proved that given a *sequence of real numbers* $m(E_n)$, with the property that $m(A_n)\leq m(E_n)\leq m(B_n)$, and $\lim m(A_n)=\lim m(B_n) = M$, then $m(E_n)$ converges to $M$.

Comment: Yea, that wasn't that great. Thanks both for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this proof is pretty much nonsense. A giant red flag is where you conclude that $A = B$ after having only assumed that $A \subseteq B$ and $m(A) = m(B)$.  There are a huge number of counterexamples to this, e.g.

$$[0, 1] \subseteq [0, 1] \cup \{2\} \subseteq [0, 1] \cup \{2, 3\}$$

Recall that the quantities $A_n, A$, etc. are *sets*. Not real numbers.